# Python, удалить элементы None из списка

Tags: python, list

Получаю список из БД
Подскажите как удалить элементы None и оставить только IP

```
rows = [(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 2), (None, 3), ('10.10.1.103', 3), ('10.10.1.101', 1), ('10.10.1.102', 2)]
```

чтобы на выходе получилось [('10.10.1.103', 3), ('10.10.1.101', 1), ('10.10.1.102', 2)]

Comment: `[r for r in rows if r[0]]`

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый ответ! Я уже часа два гуглю без пользы )

Comment: Еще стоит посмотреть в направлении функции `filter()`, которая примерно тоже самое делает https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i for i in rows if i[0] is not None]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = [(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 2), (None, 3), ('10.10.1.103', 3), ('10.10.1.101', 1), ('10.10.1.102', 2)]
IPs = list(filter(lambda i: i[0], rows))
```

Этот код фильтрует каждый элемент (в лямбде) списка rows (всё с помощью функции filter, можете загуглить если не понятно). И на выходе мы получаем именно то что вам надо

```
[('10.10.1.103', 3), ('10.10.1.101', 1), ('10.10.1.102', 2)]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]